# What is the use of protocols directory in Sproutcore?

Tags: sproutcore

While learning about build tools in sproutcore I came across the config option below which allows that files in directories named "protocols" are included in the build.

`:load_protocols => {Boolean}`

But my primary question is what is this `protocols` directory? What is the significance of it?

Answer (score 1):

Today I got answer from my senior at work. I love to share with the community

Protocols exist so that methods can be document with JSDoc without being included in a class.

For example, SC.ResponderProtocol documents methods like mouseDown. If you implement mouseDown in your SC.View subclass, it will be called. But if you don't implement it, there' s no default (empty) implementation in SC.View, which would just add overhead to make a no-op method call.

The protocols directory exists a place to gather them together, but since the implementation are just placeholders, and not actually used anywhere, they're not included in a production build.

Answer (score 0):

Protocols are various interfaces without implementations. If you expect an object to implement a particular set of methods, you would define a protocol for that; this would then be placed in the protocols directory.